# Как сделать управление камеры от первого лица на телефоны

Tags: c#, unity3d, mobile

Не могу понять как сделать управление камерой на телефоны как в других играх, я хочу добиться результата как в Standoff 2, Minecraft и наверно любого шутера от первого лица. С тем как это сделать на пк я разобрался, но с мобилками я не понимаю принцип работы с Touch. Заранее, спасибо!